# Git pull on server using cronjob

Tags: linux, git, cron

I was trying to create a task to pull the latest commits from bitbucket repo to my server. 
It seems like cronjob is running but not pulling my latest commits.

The entry i tried is

```
*/5 * * * * rayan cd /home/rayan/design && git pull origin master
```

It doesn't work, and I don't know how to debug it. Could someone help?

Comment: What's `rayan` that's right before `cd`? This doesn't seem to be a command.

Comment: that's the username

Comment: You don't put username there. Just the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't suggest to automate this task with Crontab, becasue you may get a merge conflict, and Crontab can not resovle that.

Comment: so any other suggestions?

Comment: Do it manually whenever you need. or at least use `git fetch` instead of `git pull`.
`git fetch` get the chagnes from the remote repo, and let you decide wheter to merge them or not.